# QP solver for Java

Tags: java, mathematical-optimization, numerical, solver, quadratic

I'm looking for a good easy to use Java based Quadratic Programming (QP) solver.

Googling around I came across ojAlgo (http://ojalgo.org).

However, I was wondering if there are any other/better alternatives.

Comment: Which QP solver did you end up using?

Comment: @dsg - I couldn't find a QP solver inside Apache Commons Math and I wasn't sure how much community support was behind ojAlgo. So, I just ended up writing my own, but still build upon Apache Commons Math.

Comment: @dsg - Not yet. It's part of JavaNLP (http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/index.shtml). But, it hasn't been released to the public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/). I haven't used ojalgo, and I really can't say I've used Commons Lang enough to be able to provide you with a lot of details, but it did do what I needed.

Description from their website:

> Commons Math is a library of
>   lightweight, self-contained
>   mathematics and statistics components
>   addressing the most common problems
>   not available in the Java programming
>   language or Commons Lang.
>
> Guiding principles:
>
> 1. Real-world application use cases determine development priority.
> 2. This package emphasizes small, easily integrated components rather
>      than large libraries with complex
>      dependencies and configurations.
> 3. All algorithms are fully documented and follow generally
>      accepted best practices.
> 4. In situations where multiple standard algorithms exist, a Strategy
>      pattern is used to support multiple
>      implementations.
> 5. Limited dependencies. No external dependencies beyond Commons
>      components and the core Java platform
>      (at least Java 1.3 up to version 1.2
>      of the library, at least Java 5
>      starting with version 2.0 of the
>      library).

Answer (score 1):

SuanShu has implemented the [Active Set method](https://nm.dev/html/javadoc/nmdev/dev/nm/solver/multivariate/constrained/convex/sdp/socp/qp/solver/activeset/package-summary.html) to solve quadratic programming problem.
Examples are found here:

http://redmine.numericalmethod.com/projects/public/repository/entry/Examples/src/main/java/com/numericalmethod/suanshu/examples/QuadraticProgramming.java