# How Can I Use ojAlgo To Solve Quadratic Programming (QP) in Java?

Tags: java, mathematical-optimization, quadratic, ojalgo

I have a quadratic programming problem (quadratic objective function with linear constraints, integer variables) that I want to solve in Java. ojAlgo seems capable of this. Unfortunately, I can't find documentation or examples for how to use it. Can anyone help me out here?

Suggestions for solving QP in Java using tools other than ojAlgo are also welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [QP solver for Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095517/qp-solver-for-java)

Comment: I saw that question, but it basically went unanswered. Commons Math doesn't seem to have a QP solver, and I'm not going to implement my own. This question is specifically about how to use ojAlgo.

Comment: Not sure if you've seen it but the last answer seems to provide an implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [JOptimizer](http://www.joptimizer.com) , an open source java convex optimization library. There are a lot of examples and explanations for QP and other optimization problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples on how to use ojAlgo's optimization functionality:

https://github.com/optimatika/ojAlgo/wiki/Optimisation

Also, if you get the source code, the unit tests provide plenty examples on how to use the various classes.